# How to select a span element which is a list box ,when multiple span elements with same class ID are present in the same page?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I am using robot framework to test a GUI application , I need to select a span element which is a list box , but I have multiple span elements with same class ID in the same page  , So how can I select each span element(list box) ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a part of your code you use to get the span element and a part of your GUI application where you are trying to get the element from (HTML, or smth.)?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides various ways to locate elements in the page. If you can't use id, consider using CSS or Xpath.